# Homomorphism between modules and Jacobson radical

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules

> Let $R$ be a (not necessarily commutative) ring. Let $M$ be a (left) $R$-module. If $N$ is a submodule of $M$, then prove that $$ (N+ \operatorname{rad}(M)) /N \subset \operatorname{rad}(M/N).$$
>
> Here, $\operatorname{rad}(M)$ denotes [the Jacobson radical](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Radical_of_a_module) of $M$, i.e. the intersection of all maximal submodules of $M$.

I tried to prove using the fact that:

If $f: A \to B$  is a homomorphism between modules then $f(\operatorname{rad}A) \subset \operatorname{rad} B$ but I didn't succed to construct such a homorphism.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you well guessed one can use a homomorphism: just take $f:M\to M/N$ the canonical surjection, that is, $f(x)=x\pmod N$. Then $f(\operatorname{rad}(M))\subseteq\operatorname{rad}(M/N)$. But $$f(\operatorname{rad}(M))=(N+\operatorname{rad}(M))/N$$ and you are done.

Comment: Thank you! It wasn't that hard finally.

Answer (score 2):

Give a maximal submodule $I \subset B$, then $f^{-1}(I)$ is a maximal submodule of $A$, thus $radA \subset f^{-1}(radB)$. So $f(radA) \subset fof^{-1}(radB) \subset radB$.